# Is it possible to stir the tea so that it cools more slowly?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics

I recently learned that stirring the tea with vertical movements speeds up the cooling process. As a result, I had a question, and whether it is possible to stir it so that it cools down, as slowly as possible. Conditions: the spoon is an aluminum tea spoon, take its shape as a rectangle, the temperature of the tea is 363K, normal environmental conditions.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how exactly "vertical movements" accelerate the cooling?

Comment: *I recently learned that stirring the tea with vertical movements speeds up the cooling process.* Do you have a ref. for that?

Comment: If you stir vigourously enough, the work done by stirring may be able to heat up the tea (although I am not sure whether that would be significant enough to be noticeable).

Answer (score 2):

Stirring helps *heat transfer* (i.o.w. cooling) because it decreases the film thickness of the tea boundary layer with the cup and thereby increases the *convection heat transfer coefficient $h$*.

Stirring also ensures the tea is at homogeneous temperature, which maximises the temperature difference between the tea and the environment and this, in accordance with Newton's law of cooling, also promotes heat transfer.

*So stirring always increases cooling rate*. The only way to minimise cooling rate is to stir as slowly as possible.

[Newton's law of cooling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_law_of_cooling#Mathematical_formulation_of_Newton%27s_law) is formulated mathematically as:

$$\dot{Q}=hA\Delta T$$

where $\dot{Q}$ is the rate of heat transfer, $h$ is convection heat transfer coefficient and $\Delta T$ is the temperature difference between the tea and the environment.

Comment: what about not stirring at all?  Just sitting there.

Comment: @Natsfan People stir to mix in sugar, milk, lemon, sweetener etc. Instant coffee also needs initial stirring.

Comment: Yes I know, i'm a coffee drinker.  i was just asking about your statement that only way to minimize cooling rateis to stir as slowly as possible.  Is no stirring (lets say i like my coffee black) the slowest cooling rate?

Comment: @Natsfan Yes, no stirring reduces  heat transfer (cooling)

Comment: > *"the tea is at homogeneous temperature, which maximises the temperature difference between the tea and the environment"* -- Making $T$ uniform increases $\Delta T$ (wrt cup or air) only at boundary points where $T$ of tea increases due to stirring (bottom). At other points $T$ decreases due to stirring (top). Stirring speeding up the cooling process overall is very unintuitive. Perhaps increased evaporation surface and heat transfer to the teaspoon play major roles.

Comment: Have you considered viscous heating?

Comment: @JánLalinský    *"Stirring speeding up the cooling process overall is very unintuitive."* No, not at all. See this resource e.g. on $h$: https://ahtt.mit.edu/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/AHTTv500.pdf

Comment: @ChetMiller: No, I didn't consider that because I believe its contribution to be very small.

Comment: It all depends on how the stirring is implemented.  If it is done in the usual way using a spoon in a cup, then viscous heating will not be significant.  But, if it is done by placing the tea between two closely spaced concentric rotating cylinders (like a journal bearing), and the inner cylinder is rotated very rapidly, the tea can definitely  be kept warm.

Comment: @ChetMiller Sure, but that's hardly in the spirit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

There are more factors involved here.

Stirring in a way than causes turbulence does not have the same effect as stirring in circles, creating a vortex. Moreover, heat loss due to evaporation and surface radiation may or may not exceed heat loss due to wall contact, depending on environmental conditions and the choice of material the cup is made of.

In general, convection itself does not cool the tea down at all, unless it can make it flow out of the cup. Convection merely facilitates radiation, evaporation and conduction. In this sense, making the tea less temperature homogeneous by stirring the hotter tea away from the surfaces, may have an insulating effect. Vortex flow being known to concentrate heat in its center, like in a vortex tube, supports the possibility of this. I have however no knowledge of experiments in this respect.

.